# how to compare column values in 2 dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, conditional-statements

I need to compare two dataframes df1 and df2. If the name in df1 equals to the name in df2, I need to combine the mylist to df2.
This is mylist datarame:
mylist :

```
      0       1
    [1,2]   [2,3]
    [1,5]   [2,6]
    [1,6]   [2,4]
    [1,1]   [2,5]
    [1,3]   [2,8]

mylist[0] = [[1,2],[2,3]]
mylist[1] = [[1,5],[2,6]]
```

This is the dataframe df1:

```
df1:
     name    0     1
0    a     [1,2]   [2,3]
1    y     [1,5]   [2,6]
2    c     [1,6]   [2,4]
3    x     [1,10]  [2,5]
4    e     [1,3]   [2,8]
```

This is the dataframe df2:

```
 df2:
   

  name    id     
0    a      abcd   
1    b      efgh
2    c      ijkl   
3    d      mnop   
4    e      qrs

If the **name** in df1 = the **name** in df2, I need to append **mylist** in df1 to df2
```

expected output =

```
df3:
       name      id     0        1
    0    a      abcd   [1,2]   [2,3]
    1    b      efgh
    2    c      ijkl   [1,6]   [2,4]
    3    d      mnop   
    4    e      qrs    [1,3]   [2,8]
```

Comment: Do you want to add columns 0 and 1 in df1 to df2?

Comment: not the whole column, if name in df1 = name in df2. ie., name[0] in df1 which is 'a' equals to name[0] in df2 ,which is also 'a', then add mylist[0] which is [[1,2],[2,3]] to df2

Comment: Not clear. What if name[5] ? Please add expected output to the question.

Comment: can you check my answer ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use merge:

```
final= df2.merge(df1,how='left', on='name')
```

Comment: ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat

Comment: In the examples you gave, it is very strange that the column is of type int64 because the name columns are made up of letters. Are you sure both name columns are strings?

Comment: yes. the column names are string except the column name in df1 which is 0,1

Comment: this is so weird. Are you sure that the columns named **name** in both dfs are strings? Are all values ​​in the **name** column strings (like a,b,c) ?

Comment: all values in the name coumns are the type : numpy.int64

Comment: i converted them to str, but when i run this code i get all values in 0,1 as NaN

Comment: write `df.head(5)` and write output to the question please.